What is $\mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} X_i X_{i-k} < x\right)$ where $X_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal variables?
Let $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_{N-1}$ be i.i.d. standard normal variables, i.e. $X_i \sim N(0,1)$.
I want to know what the pdf of the random variable $Y_{N,k} = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} X_i X_{i-k}$ is, with the stipulation that indices are mod $N$. This is the lagged autocovariance of Gaussian noise. It's a bit of pain in the neck finding any related literature so I am hoping someone can point me to anything.
Some examples:
$$ Y_{1,0} \sim X_0^2 $$
$$ Y_{2,1} \sim 2 X_0 X_1 $$
$$ Y_{3,1} \sim X_0 X_1 + X_1 X_2 + X_2 X_0 $$
Now for $k=0$, we have a chi-squared distribution. For $N=2, k=1$, we have the product of two normal variables, which is known. But the third is more interesting. Right now I am unsure of how to deal with the sum of non-independent random varibles.
I suspect that $ Y_{N, k_1} = Y_{N,k_2} $ for $N > 2$ and $k_1 \neq 0 \neq k_2$. Can anyone show this?
The mean isn't that hard to determine. For $k=0$ we have a chi squared distribution. For $k\neq 0$, since expectation is linear and each term is made of independent random variables, we have $E[Y_{N,k}] = \sum 0 \cdot 0 = 0$. It is likely easy to figure out the variance.
Any partial answers are helpful!

I think that $\mathop{\mathbb E}(Y_{N,k})=0$ unless $k\equiv 0,\text{ (mod $N$)}$.

Let $N\in\mathbb N_+$ and pick a sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N$ of iid standard normal variables. Extend it to a sequence $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ such that
\begin{align}X_i=X_j, &&\text{if $i\equiv j$ (mod $N$)}.\end{align}
Define, for $k\in\mathbb Z$,
$$
Y_{N,k} := \sum_{i=1}^NX_{i}X_{i-k}.
$$
Obviously, we have that $Y_{N,k}=Y_{N,k+hN}$, for all $h\in\mathbb Z$. Hence, we can focus our attention on the case $k\in\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$.
We'll mark the index of the $X$'s using red whenever it falls outside $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ (i.e. we'll write $X_\color{red}{-2}$ instead of $X_{-2}$).
If $k=0$ we have
$$Y_{N,0}=\sum_{i=1}^NX_{i}^2\sim\mathcal X^2(N).$$
If $k\in\{1,2,\dots,N-1\}$ we have
\begin{align}
Y_{N,k}&=\sum_{i=1}^kX_{i}X_{\color{red}{i-k}}+\sum_{i=k+1}^NX_{i}X_{i-k}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^kX_{i}X_{i+N-k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^NX_{i}X_{i-k}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^kX_{i}X_{i+N-k}+\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}X_{i}X_{i+k},
\end{align}
so it is straightforward that $Y_{N,N-k} = Y_{N,k}$, for all $k\in\{1,\dots,N-1\}$.
Recall that
$$Y_{N,k}=\sum_{i=1}^kX_{i}X_{i+N-k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^NX_{i}X_{i-k}.$$
Consider the permutation $\sigma:i\mapsto\sigma(i)$ defined by the law
\begin{cases}
i\mapsto i+N-k, &\text{if $i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$},\\
i\mapsto i-k, &\text{if $i\in\{k+1,k+2,\dots,N\}$},
\end{cases}
and the associated permutation matrix $$\left(P_\sigma\right)_{i,j}=\delta_{j,\sigma(i)}=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if $j=\sigma(i)$,}\\ 0,&\text{if $j\ne\sigma(i)$.}\end{cases}$$
Let $X = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N)^T$ be a column vector, then
$$Y_{N,k}=\frac12X^TAX,$$
where $A=P_\sigma+P_\sigma^T$. In fact,
\begin{align}
\frac12X^TAX&=\frac12X^TP_\sigma X+\frac12X^TP_\sigma^TX\\&=\frac12X^T P_\sigma X + \frac12\left(X^T P_\sigma^T X\right)^T\\&=X^T P_\sigma X\\&= \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NX_i\delta_{j,\sigma(i)}X_j=\sum_{i=1}^NX_iX_{\sigma(i)}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^kX_iX_{i+N-k}+\sum_{i=k+1}^NX_iX_{i-k}\\&=Y_{N,k}.
\end{align}
To compute the eigenvalues of $A$, define $d:=N/\gcd(N,k)\ge2$ and note that the permutation $\sigma$ can be decomposed into the product of $N/d$ disjoint cycles of length $d$.
For example, if $N=10$ and $k=4$ we have $\sigma=(1,7,3,9,5)(2,8,4,10,6)$.
The characteristic polynomial of a permutation matrix $P_\tau$ is
$$\det(\lambda I - P_\tau)=\prod_{h = 1}^N (\lambda^h-1)^{C_h},$$
where $C_h$ is the number of cycles of length $h$ in the decomposition of $\tau$ into disjoint cycles. Thus, with the help of the $d$-th roots of unity, we get
\begin{align}
\det(\lambda I -P_\sigma) &= (\lambda^d-1)^\frac{N}{d}
\\&=\prod_{h=1}^{d}\left(\lambda-\exp\left\{i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right\}\right)^\frac{N}{d}.
\end{align}
Now, since permutation matrices are orthogonal, we have $$A=P_\sigma+P_\sigma^T=P_\sigma+P_\sigma^{-1}.$$

Fact: If $M$ is an invertible matrix, then the characteristic polynomial of $M+M^{-1}$ is
$$
p_{\!_{\,M+M^{-1}}}(\lambda)=\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(M)}\left(\lambda-\mu-\frac1\mu\right),
$$
where $\sigma(M)$ is the multiset of the eigenvalues of $M$. To see that, take a Schur decomposition of $M$, say
$$M=QUQ^{-1},$$
where $Q$ is an unitary matrix and $U$ is an upper triangular matrix. Since $M^{-1}=QU^{-1}Q^{-1}$, we get
\begin{align}
p_{\!_{\,M+M^{-1}}}(\lambda) &= \det\left(\lambda I-M-M^{-1}\right)\\&=\det\left(Q\left(\lambda I-U-U^{-1}\right)Q^{-1}\right)
\\&=\det\left(\lambda I-U-U^{-1}\right)\\&=\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(M)}\left(\lambda-\mu-\frac1\mu\right).
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the fact that the matrix $\lambda I-U-U^{-1}$ is upper triangular; therefore its determinant is equal to the product of the diagonal elements.

Hence the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
\begin{align}
p_{\!_{\,A}}(\lambda)&= \det\left(\lambda I-P_\sigma-P_\sigma^{-1}\right)
\\&=\prod_{h=1}^{d}\left[\lambda - \left(\exp\left\{i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right\}+\exp\left\{i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right\}^{-1}\right)\right]^\frac{N}{d}
\\&= \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left[\lambda - \left(\exp\left\{i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right\}+\exp\left\{-i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right\}\right)\right]^\frac{N}{d}
\\&= \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left[\lambda - 2\cosh\left(i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right]^\frac{N}{d}
\\&= \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left[\lambda - 2\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right]^\frac{N}{d}.
\end{align}
Finally, compute the moment generating function of $Y_{N,k}$. In a sufficiently small neighborhood of $t=0$, (we need $I-tA$ to be positive definite) we have
\begin{align}
m_{\!_{\,Y_{N,k}}}(t)&=\mathop{\mathbb E}\left[\exp\left\{\frac12tX^TAX\right\}\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{N}{2}}\int_{\mathbb R^N}\exp\left\{\frac12tx^TAx\right\}\exp\left\{-\frac12x^Tx\right\}\,dx
\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{N}{2}}\int_{\mathbb R^N}\exp\left\{-\frac12x^T\left(I-tA\right)x\right\}\,dx
\\&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{N}{2}}(2\pi)^\frac{N}{2}\left(\det\left(I-tA\right)\right)^{-\frac12}
\\&=\left(t^N\det\left(\frac{1}{t}I-A\right)\right)^{-\frac12}
\\&=\left(t^{N} p_{\!_{\,A}}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)^{-\frac12}
\\&=\left(t^{N} \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left[\frac1t - 2\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right]^\frac{N}{d}\right)^{-\frac12}
\\&= \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left(1 - 2t\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right)^{-\frac{N}{2d}}.
\end{align}
Let $Z_1,\dots,Z_d$ be iid $\mathcal X^2(\frac{N}{d})$ distributed.
Define the random variable $$Z:=\sum_{h=1}^d\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)Z_h.$$
The mgf of $Z$ is
\begin{align}
m_{{\!}_{\,Z}}(t)&=\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\exp\left\{tZ\right\}\right)
\\&=\prod_{h=1}^{d}\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(\exp\left\{t\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)Z_h\right\}\right)
\\&=\prod_{h=1}^{d}\mathop{m_{{\!}_{\,Z_1\!}}}\left(t\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right)
\\&= \prod_{h=1}^{d}\left(1 - 2t\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right)^{-\frac{N}{2d}}
\\&=m_{\!_{\,Y_{N,k}\!}}(t).
\end{align}
Hence $Y_{N,k}$ is a linear combination of $d=\frac{N}{\gcd(N,k)}$ iid $\mathcal X^2(\gcd(N,k))$ - distributed random variables, namely
$$Y_{N,k}\overset{d}{=}\sum_{h=1}^{N/\gcd(N,k)}\cos\left(\frac{2h\gcd(N,k)\pi}{N}\right)Z_h.$$
Finally, we compute mean and variance. Since $d\ge2$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb E}(Y_{N,k})&=\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_h)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{d}\Re\exp\left(i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\Re\left(\sum_{h=1}^{d}\exp\left(i\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\Re\left(\sum_{h=1}^{d}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)^h\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\Re\left(\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)\frac{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)^{d}-1}{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)-1}\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathbb E}(Z_1)\Re\left(\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)\frac{\exp\left(2\pi i\right)-1}{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)-1}\right)=0
\end{align}
Let's compute the variance
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Y_{N,k})&=\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos^2\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)\mathop{Var}(Z_h)
\\&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos^2\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right).
\end{align}
If $k=\frac{N}{2}$ (i.e. $d=2$), we have
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Y_{N,k})&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{2h\pi}{2}\right)
\\&=2\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)=2N,
\end{align}
while, if $k\ne\frac{N}{2}$ (i.e. $d\ge3$), we get
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Y_{N,k})&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos^2\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos^2\left(\frac{2h\pi}{d}\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\frac12\sum_{h=1}^{d}\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{4h\pi}{d}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\frac12\left(d+\sum_{h=1}^{d}\cos\left(\frac{4h\pi}{d}\right)\right)
\\&=\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}(Z_1)\frac12(d+0)
\\&=2\gcd(N,k)\frac12d=N.
\end{align}
To see that the last summation is $0$, proceed like we did in the computation of the expectation.

Please keep edits to a minimum!

Very nice! It will take me some time to go through every detail, but the argument makes sense. Thanks!
